# how to bind button with text with Seekbar thumb at run time

Tags: android, seekbar

Hi I want to bind button with text with seekbar thumb. so that if I move the seekbar thumb the button with dynamic text move along with that.

[image]
Please suggest how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like below:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seekbar_test);

    seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       
        @Override       
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {            
        }       
        @Override       
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        }       
        @Override       
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            setTxt(progress);
        }
    });
}

private void setTxt(int prg)
{
    text.setX((float)prg);
}
```

Comment: I have to move text along with the button. but thats on its place only

Comment: you want to move text of button.??

Comment: On button text will be there So I have to move button along with that the text written in button should change on progess of seekbarthumb.

Comment: Yes That i Have done but it on the same position not moving with the seek bar. I am posting an image how I want please check

Comment: @User3030365 is it helpful??

Comment: ohk.. let me check again

Comment: Solved finally... Thanks a ton :)